# How to get canvas from postcompose event of map in openlayers 6

Tags: javascript, dictionary, canvas, openlayers, openlayers-6

We are using openlayers and in version 5.3 we were using this construction:

```
map.once('postcompose', async(event) => {
  let canvas = event.context.canvas;
  // doing something with canvas
}
```

But in openLayers 6.0 the argument context is undefined for **event** (which of course broke our application).

I read [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.0.0) that:

*Layers are no longer composed to a single Canvas element. Instead, they are added to the map viewport as individual elements.*

So how do I get the canvas of a single layer?

I also read [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render_Event-RenderEvent.html) that:

*Canvas context. Not available when the event is dispatched by the map. Only available when a Canvas renderer is used, null otherwise.*

Is it somehow possible to set canvas renderer to all the layers so that CanvasRenderingContext2D is not undefined for the 'postcompose' **event**?

Comment: each layer has it own canvas, which can be used in `layer.on('postrender', ....);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ol6 use `postrender` event on layers and new `getVectorContext` function provides access to the immediate vector rendering API.
See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.0.0

To get render context on a single layer:

```
import {getVectorContext} from 'ol/render';

// construct your map and layers as usual

layer.on('postrender', function(event) {
  const vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
  // use any of the drawing methods on the vector context
});
```